# SSO on Maintaining session in 2 different servers

Tags: session, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

Sorry if this is a bit long. Got a requirement to integrate our application with client's main portal site. The portal is maintained with a SAML 2.0 SSO features and as such, we'll need to integrate our login using SAML 2.0 as well.

The integration is done via an iframe, i.e. on the main portal, an iframe with the url pointing to our application. When user is logged in and click on a menu link, he/she will be presented with the iframe page, with our session checking with their IDP to make sure they are valid users. If so, then our application will continue to load as per usual.

The issue is that we'll need to maintain our session on our servers, while they shall maintain the session on their app server. If the user stayed on our site for a while, the session on the client main portal will timeout. And when the user click on the main portal link, they will be required to log in again.

It is suggested that when the user tries to navigate to the main portal pages, it will call a service (for now assuming it's an IDP) on our end to check whether the user session is valid or not. If it is, then we need to return a SAML response to them to validate the user.

We're exploring setting up an IDP service at our end to facilitates this, but it seems to be overkill to me. Is there a way for an IDP to only provides check on a user's session? Or is there a better option for us to achieve this?

Things that could not be changed:

```
1. SSO language: SAML 2.0
2. Server: Weblogic 10+
3. HTTPS a must.
```

Appreciate any suggestion or feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: Loading your application in an iFrame means that the portal is still active as well. Session shouldn't be an issue, as long as you don't have a session cookie clash... I would suggest that you get your application working with SAML, make the connection with their IdP, get that working, and then have them embed your application with the iFrame. I would bet that it "just works."

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided information, I assume your application runs on WebLogic 10+. If the remote server too uses WebLogic you might be able to just implement the SAML authentication between the WebLogic federation. 
This will simplify everything and you don't need to do complicated application customization.

If the remote site does implement SAML and not on WebLogic, you still should be able to implement SAML authentication through the WebLogic configuration. This is straightforward and can be done without much hassle.

However, please be reminded that WebLogic 10+ does not support SAML SSO logout. Therefore, this needs to be handled separately.